# _copywebapplication, missing file

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a webproject that has an PostBuildEvent like this:

`copy "$(ProjectDir)......\myfile.xml" "$(TargetDir).."`

Everything works fine when I build locally. However when the TFS-server builds the project the copied file are not present in the PublishedWebSites folder.

I know it is not ideal to have a PostBuildEvent like this, but is there a simple workaround? I don't want to have the copied file as a content file in the project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it with relative path.

```
<Content Include="..\Common\myfile.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: Another solution that seemed to work was to add an AfterbuildTarget that made a copy to $(WebProjectOutputDir)